# pandas stacking dataframe reshapes data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to stack two 3 column data frames using either concat, append, or merge. The result is a 5 column dataframe where the original columns have a different order in places. Here are some of the things I've tried:

```
dfTrain = pd.read_csv("agr_hi_train.csv")
dfTrain2 = pd.read_csv("english/agr_en_train.csv")
dfTrain2.reset_index()
frames = [dfTrain, dfTrain2]
test = dfTrain2.append(dfTrain, ignore_index=True)
test2 = dfTrain2.append(dfTrain)
test3 = pd.concat(frames, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
test4 = pd.merge(dfTrain,dfTrain2, right_index=True, left_index=True)
```

With the following results:

```
print(dfTrain.shape)
print(dfTrain2.shape)
print(test.shape)
print(test2.shape)
print(test3.shape)
print(test4.shape)
```

Output is:

(20198, 5)
(20198, 5)
(11998, 6)
(8200, 6)
(8200, 3)
(11998, 3)

I want the result to be:

(20198,3) # i.e. last two stacked on top of each other. . . 
Any ideas why I'm getting the extra columns, etc.?

Comment: Try `df.columns` to see what are the column labels. I guess they are different and hence they are treated as different columns.

Comment: You can rename the columns so they are all the same. Especially since you only have 6 total columns.

Comment: Yes, there was a subtle difference in the column names. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different column names, then your append will separate the columns.  For example:

```
dfTrain = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8200, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
dfTrain2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(11998, 3), columns=['D', 'E', 'F'])
test = dfTrain.append(dfTrain2)
print(test)
```

has the output:

```
          A         B         C         D         E         F
0      0.617294  0.507264  0.330792       NaN       NaN       NaN
1      0.439806  0.355340  0.757864       NaN       NaN       NaN
2      0.740674  0.332794  0.530613       NaN       NaN       NaN
...
20195       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.295392  0.621741  0.255251
20196       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.096586  0.841174  0.392839
20197       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.071756  0.998280  0.451681
```

If you rename the columns in both dataframes to match, then it'll line up.

```
dfTrain2.columns = ['A','B','C']
test2 = dfTrain.append(dfTrain2)
print(test2)

          A         B         C
0      0.545936  0.103332  0.939721
1      0.258807  0.274423  0.262293
2      0.374780  0.458810  0.955040
...
[20198 rows x 3 columns]
```